# presence on Facebook Canvas, appwarp android game

Tags: android, facebook, appwarp

I created an Android Game using Appwarp and now I want to connect players using facebook.  I read the docs for a few hours and now I am uncertain where to go next.  I understand Game Requests in facebook requires "presence on Facebook Canvas".  How do you do that? My app is a game and is already released on the app store with random matchmaking enabled, why doesn't facebook recognise this app as a game?

I tried GameRequestDialog, but returns error only available to games.

For games without presence on facebook canvas I seem to understand you have to use ShareDialog (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#message-dialog) or AppInviteDialog (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/archive/docs/app-invites/android/)?

bottom line, What I really want is for a player to see a list of his/her friends click on it and be matched with that person in game with appwarp, how can I achieve this? Do I have to do something to get presence on the facebook canvas or is there another way?

EDIT :
after more digging I realized Google's firebase push notifications devices to devices might be what i really want, unless someone thinks that is not feasible?

Comment: Facebook canvas would only make sense, if you have a version of your game that is _playable_ directly on there. If not, you will not get this through the review process in the first place. App Invites are deprecated, according to the docs page you referred to.

Comment: I think the requirement for canvas is in place, so that users do not have to use a specific device or platform, when they get invited to your game.

Comment: #04FS thanks for comment, is it complicated to put a java android app on facebook canvas?

Comment: Canvas / the Web Platform for games is stuff that gets loaded into an iframe on facebook.com. It’s mainly HTML / JS based, but also supports game engines like Unity for example. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/gamesonfacebook/porting